# How to educate asker when being beaten by rep hunters

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality, fastest-gun

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376868/sql-statement-join-to-fetch-result-from-multiple-tables) today and I knew the answer right away. It was in fact a question on a very basic SQL query (full joins) that most people should pick up in their first few lessons on SQL. The OP just stated his requirement with some sample data but showed no research on his part. Rather than answering the question straight away and waiting for my 15 reputation points to come, I dropped a comment asking the OP to show what he had tried and waited for an update on his question. I already had a mental draft of the answer and even looked up for a tutorial link to provide additional information.

However, before the OP could respond, along came another user who just flat out gave the answer needed by the OP. Thus, I lost an opportunity to educate the asker, the OP went on his way with his solution without being told that his question was not of the expected SO standard, the answerer went away with his 15 rep points and another two specks of dirt fell over the SO policy.

I know I can downvote the question to reflect my disdain at the OP's lack of effort. But downvoting a correct answer does not serve the intended purpose. (I don't yet have enough rep to downvote, but that's beside the point.)

How should I, as a responsible user, deal with a situation like this as I strive to adhere to the SO policy when asking or answering questions?

Comment: This is a poor question that will almost certainly not help anyone else. But still: didn't the other user educate the OP? Also, the answer requires basic knowledge, but it is not simple. The answer is good, it contains working code, and talks about edge cases. It also came 50 minutes after the question. This isn't a quick answer like you describe, and isn't fair to the other user.

Comment: First off, IMO your comment comes across as not really being helpful.  We've blocked the "What have you tried?" comments because they are not considerably constructive and you went around that but adding "I have a solution..." To me, that is not constructive and doesn't make it seem like you are trying to help the user.

Comment: @bluefeet: Is it bad practice to expect to be shown some effort from the OP before providing an answer? While it might not have seemed apparent, but I was keen on helping, albeit the user show what attempts he has made to solve the problem himself.

Comment: At least there are some Karma, answerer will probably never help the OP to modify its query according to his comment.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I'm not saying that.  I'm saying there are more constructive ways to ask this same question.  IMO, it's unhelpful and if I were that user, I'd not be inclined to respond to you.

Comment: @bluefeet: Can you enlighten me please on how I should ask that question in more constructive ways? (My SO account was activated 10 months ago, but I've been regularly active for less than a month now. I would love to get some guidance.)

Comment: @CodeNewbie - I'd say something like: "This looks like a simple `outer join`. Can you please describe what you did try, and why it didn't work for you? Also, it is grate that you include sample data and expected result, but it would be much more useful as text instead of a screenshot."

Comment: @Kobi: I didn't refute the quality of the answer. It was a splendid, to-the-point answer that worked perfectly. Thank you for that alternate comment, will remember it in future situations.

Comment: @CodeNewbie - Well, you did start the question with "being beaten by rep scores". The best you can do is downvote the answer, explain why it is bad, and *hope* the user reads your comment. It is OK to do that *and* answer the question.

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, in retrospect, that wasn't the right term to use. I realized it seemed judgemental on my part, and edited it myself. Would downvoting the answer be right, considering that there was no flaw with the quality of the answer?

Comment: see **[Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)**

Comment: I wouldn't bother really. I've seen the same, to the extent of >10k rep users answering questions marked as duplicated. Just move on...

Answer (score 14):

Your comment to the user was:

> I have the solution but please tell me first, what have you tried so far? –  CodeNewbie 4 hours ago

This comes across as not really being helpful. The "What have you tried" comment have been blocked because they are not considerably constructive. You got around that by also including "I have a solution..." but that doesn't make the comment any better. To me, that is not constructive and doesn't make it seem like you are trying to help the user.

If I was the user and you commented that way, I probably wouldn't have responded to you because you seem to really be passing by and, IMO, being unhelpful.

Yes, we expect that a user include any attempts at solving the problem, there are, however, much better ways to ask that in a comment. You could say something similar to "*Thanks for providing the table details, sample data as a visual to get your solution.  It would be extremely helpful if you also including any attempts that you made in getting the final result. It could be that you have a minor syntax issue with the FULL JOIN that needs to be adjusted.*"

We are always going to have users who are willing to answer questions that don't include the attempts that were made.  The person who answered the question is a new user who created their account 7 days ago, and yet you basically called them a [rep-whore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/269164/1).  Yes, you edited your question to remove that but *sigh* this is a new user who was trying to be helpful. I've seen long-time/high-rep users post answers that are worse than that, at least they included some sort of explanation. But to answer your final question, there is no **official policy** on whether or not users should answer questions that don't include attempts.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9QR.gif